# possible Form Field Errors for ChangePasswordForm Django

Tags: django, forms, change-password, create-view

I'm trying to customize the form field errors for a changepasswordview in Django, however, to do that I believe I need to know the attribute names of the field errors so that I can do something like this:

```
class UserUpdatePassword(PasswordChangeForm):

    class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('password')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['old_password'].label = "Password antiguo"
        print(self.fields['new_password1'].error_messages)
        self.fields['new_password1'].label = "Nuevo Password"
        self.fields['new_password1'].help_text = "Mínimo 8 caracteres, números y letras"
        self.fields['new_password2'].label = "Confirmar nuevo Password"
        self.fields['new_password1'].error_messages = {'password_mismatch': "Los Passwords ingresados no son iguales",}
```

I know there are errors for password and password confirmation mismatch, when the password is not long enough, only letters or numbers, etc.  Where can I find the attribute names? (e.g. 'password_mismatch')

Answer (score 0):

Set the following class variable in your UserUpdatePassword form:

```
error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("Los Passwords ingresados no son iguales"),
    }
```

and remove

```
self.fields['new_password1'].error_messages = {'password_mismatch': "Los Passwords ingresados no son iguales",}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.error_messages['password_incorrect'] = "El Password ingresado es incorrecto"
    self.error_messages['password_mismatch'] = "Los Passwords ingresados no son iguales"
    self.fields['old_password'].label = "Password antiguo"
    self.fields['new_password1'].label = "Nuevo Password"
    self.fields['new_password1'].help_text = "Mínimo 8 caracteres, números y letras"
    self.fields['new_password2'].label = "Confirmar nuevo Password"
    print(self.errors['new_password2'])
```

However, there is a set of errors that I cannot manage to customize.  They are in the last line of code I pasted above.  "self.errors['new_password2']" delivers a list, which I can access only with integers.  For example "This password is too short" is self.errors['new_password2'][0] .  In order to customize it, I'd need to access it rather like self.errors['new_password2']['password_too_short'], of course this is not possible.  Any ideas?